# How to define that an object can only contain specific values (depending on the key)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

**Question**

How can I define a record type `Shape<RootType>` whose values (if specified) can only be "A" if the key can index `RootType` and either "B" or "C" otherwise?

**Test cases**

```js
type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  unused: number;
}

declare function test<T extends Shape<User>>(): void;

// The following should compile:
test<{
  id: "A",
  name: "A",
  something: "B",
  else: "C",
}>();

// The followings shouldn't compile:
test<{ id: "B" }>(); // `id` should only be "A"
test<{ name: 123 }>(); // `name` should only be "A"
test<{ something: "A" }>(); // extra keys can only be "B" or "C"
```

**What have I tried?**

```js
type Shape<RootType> = {
  [KeyType in symbol]?:
    KeyType extends RootType
      ? "A"
      : "B" | "C"
}
```

I've tried the above but that type seems to extend whatever record type.

Comment: What makes `id` and `name` special vs. `something` or `else`? You've mentioned `RootType`, but haven't shown it. Are they properties of that? What is the `User` type?

Comment: Please update the question with a [mre] with **all** necessary types to replicate the problem. (One good way to ensure you've done that is to put it in the question and *also* provide a link to [the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) with the same code in it, ensuring nothing is undefined and that the problem is shown. [Just beware of [this stupid SE issue with playground links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386543/why-does-my-typescript-playground-link-break-when-i-use-insert-hyperlink).])

Comment: Your `test` function accepts a type parameter, but no actual parameters, and has no return value. What's the purpose of the type parameter? It's erased by the compilation process. Usually, type parameters are useful where they define the types of parameters and/or the return type.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Woops sorry. Forgot to add `User` to the test case. What makes `id` and `name` special is that they are `keyof User`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The purpose of the `test` function is to check that it compiles. The valid cases under "test cases" should compile and those that are not valid shouldn't compile.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder TS playg: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkE9QIwJwPYGsCmA7UBLAtgBwDYrboAuAhiZgmgFAmS4qgDKAFmYwDwBKCCJAFQYoAfKAC8oAN41QoANoBpFJCGMsGAM6RsMBPgC6AfgBcsuaGWrhoFAA8S6ACabQvfmpTmLoI6ABEAIL+3hYmAQBC-qAAPgEAwiEAvjR0NgCqmihwEtLmmE7haACuutkA3OZoZMThmiRwmGgA5pVyxSVZhaAlZXCVKTROKADG+GRwTABmHSOU1KCO9ZwCtg7OrmwcKJyZ2SIiABQAlOEAbggFlTQgoAKs0-r4CADuTc2gmqwIxfhOoCMEHhMIQzEsSJwZHICuEgv4ADRVGooWHBRFyTRAlAkVjvWFRdG2fBZWGJRFJI7Ha63e6PfDPN4tVxfH5-NAAchIAKBuBBKLoKGWUiw3X8UVAFJO5VAtwABgVZZ9vr9-tR8NAYEw4QKhT1keEAIwAJgAzBLKdK5dViIqWSrQGqNVrgjqIcLMcQcXiAsFzVKZWB7A0yKBUJBXCMyBhHbAteKEDl-IkgA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to map over the keys of `T` and check for each key `K` if it `extends keyof RootType`. To make `T` available in `Shape`, we need to pass it to `Shape` as a generic parameter too.

```
declare function test<T extends Shape<User, T>>(): void;

type Shape<RootType, T> = {
  [K in keyof T]:
    K extends keyof RootType
      ? "A"
      : "B" | "C"
}

// The following is valid:
test<{
  id: "A",
  name: "A",
  something: "B",
  else: "C",
}>();

// The followings aren't valid:
test<{ id: "B" }>(); // `id` should only be "A"
test<{ name: 123 }>(); // `name` should only be "A"
test<{ something: "A" }>(); // extra keys can only be "B" or "C"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIFUDO0BOsC8sDexZ9gJYAmAXLIqCgQHYDmu+1AhgLbRkVV3AC+IR0AMYAbJijgAzAK7VBoAgHtqsUNAoAeACqxoAD1XUiiWAGUAFkxjqkqADSxNAPkcAKAJRkAbguIBuEBAwphZWAEoKCqCaUND2ThjYDADaANKEygDW0OAKEg4AuiQMeGl6BkawWTl54ZHRMMX4APywLgBEAIJtbo14ZO0AQm2wAD6wbQDC3bwgAPSzDmaSCsLCCgDuNLSExp5MwsRFqho4eIfjXbYMzGxknW1XeIgKbKBmW3dDjzrCyHdTVx4rjc-mA80Wy1WGy2xjE0GoAHJQLA9gdSGA1KB1FhCKRxkNYED3L5YOCAAbEMnkMwKKTCIiwJTCcCwABGcHuGJOsBu7FgAEYAEwAZkJwJJ5N5VMQNLpDKZLPZFzaXKxOOer3edDuXTFxNJCzKKCYlWyxkETGUCrZHIJCjQkzaQA)

Comment: Can't vote apparently but I'll accept the question as soon as possible. Thanks.
PS: by the way is there a way to make it so while typing in `test<{ ... }>` it can autocomplete keys from `RootType` by any chance?

Comment: @Thomas - I'm afraid not. Autocompletion is not always reliant and it seems to not understand at all what properties are can be auto completed here. Probably since every key is potentially allowed here or maybe because we use some kind of "circular" type.